# Plotting charts with google app inventor

Tags: charts, app-inventor

I'm trying to create an app with Google app inventor which can plot a graph from a database - for example: x,y values that the app will get.

Does anyone know how to do it?

During my search for some info I saw below image from [this webpage](http://www.flickr.com/photos/psychemedia/4814842687/), and if you look closely you'll see on the top (right corner) the options: **"plot chart"** and **"output chart"**, but I don't actually find these options in the app inventor menu.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do it indirectly by creating an Image component, then setting its Picture property to a URL for a [Google Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/chart_gall.html).

[image: Blocks Editor view]

[image: Designer View]